# Visual Studio 2012 Doesn't launch app when I press Start

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Ok, I'm at a loss..  I have never seen this happen before.  I am using Visual Studio.  I have been working on a regular WPF project.  It was working fine.  This morning, I made a few changes to add a .dll project to my solution and link directly to it. Now, I click the green arrow, or F5 to start debugging, and it clicks and then goes green again.  There is no debug output, the program doesn't start running.  There are no exceptions thrown.  What the heck happened?

It's a pretty big project, so I can't put any useful source code here.  I'm just wondering if anybody has ever had a case where they push F5 to start the app, and nothing happens..

Any help would be appreciated.  I am at an utter loss as to what would cause this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I am a blithering idiot.  The problem was that I had 2 instances of Visual Studio open at the same time and on the same project.  When I closed down Visual Studio, I noticed the other instance and closed it too.  Then I opened just one and everything wants to work now.

So wierd, but fixed now.

Word of warning.  Only open your project once....  :-)

Thanks to all for the help.  You all get points !!

Answer (score 2):

WPF apps usually just die without an error message if there is a problem during start-up.

You can try to configure your IDE to break on thrown exceptions:

Debug -> Exceptions:
Check the checkbox in the column *Thrown* in the row "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't break.  No exceptions are happening.  I even put a breakpoint on the first line of my 'MainWindow()' constructor, and it doesn't even get there.

Comment: Just to make sure there is no weird invalid state somewhere: Restart Visual Studio, Do a Clean & Rebuild All. Does that help?

Comment: Further things to check: Is there an entry in the event viewer?

Comment: Also, try a breakpoint on your `App.OnStartup` method, if you have one.